# Pass a PHP variable from a view to a block in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I'd like to pass a PHP variable from a view (output as a block) to a static block. In the view, I've set the footer to PHP and wrote something like this:

```
<?php $name = "Sam"; ?>
```

In the static block below it, I'm just trying to retrieve the value of that variable:

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

But alas, nothing is there. Chances are, there's a more Drupaly way to get this done... and I'm happy to go in that direction... but if at all possible, I'd like to try and make this work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add "global $name;" before both lines.

That should work, but global functions should be avoided, you should at least use a unique, somehow prefixed variable. What exactly are you trying to do specifically?

A better way would be to declare some helper functions and use a pattern that many such functions in Drupal core use, for example [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6). If you look at the first function, you can see that you can pass something to it, which is stored in a static variable and then returned. It can be called without an argument, then it just returns whatever is currently saved in it.

You could define a function like this:

```
<?php
function yourmodule_set_name($name = NULL) {
  static $stored_name = NULL;
  if ($name) {
    $stored_name = $name;
  }
  return $stored_name;
}

yourmodule_set_name('Sam');

// Prints Sam.
echo yourmodule_set_name();
?>
```

In Drupal 7, there is a helper function called [drupal_static](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) which you can directly (ab-)use for that.

```
<?php
$name = &drupal_static('yourmodule_name');
$name = 'Sam';

// Anyhwere else, prints also Sam.
echo drupal_static('yourmodule_name');
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! The global trick worked! (Why didn't I think of that?) Are there any drawbacks or pitfalls to using this method (performance?). It seems to accomplish exactly what I need, but I want to understand the full consequences before I go live. Many thanks!

Comment: Well, you are polluting the global namespace with it, another module could accidently override your global variable. It is simply discouraged to do that because you actually can not know the full consequences of it.

Answer (score -1):

If you were setting a persistent variable (one that would survive a few page loads) You could also utilize variable_set() & variable_get() to set and get a variable. Although as Berdir points out this would be fairly terrible for performance if it were happening on every page load.

In your view footer using variable_set():

```
<?php
  $name = "name";
  $value = "Sammy";
  variable_set($name, $value);
?>
```

And then in your block you could retrieve that variable using variable_get():

```
<?php
$default = "default";
$echome = variable_get("name", $default);
echo $echome;
?>
```

Comment: Note that this variable_get/set() a persistent storage, variable_set() executes UPDATE/INSERT queries and cleares the variables cache. So this is not so a function that you want to execute on every single page and that is what I understood the question is about. This is an option for a setting that you set once and then need everywhere.